# How to use the Google Closure Compiler to browserify your Node.js library

Tags: node.js, google-closure-compiler

I have this simple Node.js library:

```
mylib/
|- inc.js
|- index.js
|- is_number.js
|- package.json
```

`mylib/is_number.js`

```js
module.exports = x => typeof x === 'number';
```

`mylib/inc.js`

```js
const is_number = require('./is_number');

module.exports = x => is_number(x) ? x + 1 : x;
```

`mylib/index.js` *(value of the `main` property in my `package.json`)*

```js
module.exports = {
  inc: require('./inc'),
  utils: {
    is_number: require('./is_number')
  }
};
```

Example:

```js
const mylib = require('mylib');

mylib.inc(41);
//=> 42

mylib.utils.is_number(42);
//=> true
```

How can I use the Google Closure Compiler to "browserify" my Node.js library so that it can work in a browser too? e.g.,

```html
<script src="mylib/browser.min.js"></script>
<script>
const mylib = window.mylib;

mylib.inc(41);
//=> 42

mylib.utils.is_number(42);
//=> true
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*The canonical post for this answer is this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/customcommander/22cb5d98da3f3d4b804ed9dae6b5b109).*

### TL; DR

1. Create  `mylib/index_browser.js`

   ```js
   window.mylib = {
     inc: require('./inc'),
     utils: {
       is_number: require('./is_number')
     }
   };
   ```
2. Create `mylib/externs.js`

   ```js
   /** @externs */
   var mylib;
   var inc;
   var utils;
   var is_number;
   ```
3. Then:

   ```sh
   $ cc --compilation_level ADVANCED \
       --language_out ES5 \
       --process_common_js_modules \
       --module_resolution NODE \
       --externs mylib/externs.js \
       --isolation_mode IIFE \
       --js mylib/index_browser.js mylib/inc.js mylib/is_number.js \
       --js_output_file mylib/browser.min.js
   ```

   *Where `cc` is an alias to your Google Closure Compiler instance; see below for an example*

---

Before we start:

I wrote this alias to make it easier to invoke the Google Closure Compiler (CC)

```sh
$ alias cc="java -jar /devtools/closure-compiler/compiler.jar"
$ cc --version
Closure Compiler (http://github.com/google/closure-compiler)
Version: v20210106
```

The browserified version of the library will be compiled down to ES5.

### Step-by-step instructions

Your first attempt might look like this: just compile the exports file `mylib/index.js`

```sh
$ cc --compilation_level ADVANCED \
     --language_out ES5 \
     --js mylib/index.js
```

```
mylib/index.js:1:0: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable module is undeclared
  1| module.exports = {
     ^^^^^^

mylib/index.js:2:7: ERROR - [JSC_UNDEFINED_VARIABLE] variable require is undeclared
  2|   inc: require('./inc'),
            ^^^^^^^

2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

If CC doesn't know about `module` and `require` that's not a great start.

Fortunately we're only missing the `--process_common_js_modules` flag:

```sh
$ cc --compilation_level ADVANCED \
     --language_out ES5 \
     --process_common_js_modules \
     --js mylib/index.js
```

```
mylib/index.js:2:7: ERROR - [JSC_JS_MODULE_LOAD_WARNING] Failed to load module "./inc"
  2|   inc: require('./inc'),
            ^

mylib/index.js:4:15: ERROR - [JSC_JS_MODULE_LOAD_WARNING] Failed to load module "./is_number"
  4|     is_number: require('./is_number')
                    ^

2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Still not great but this time the errors are different:

1. CC doesn't know which `require` you're talking about
2. CC doesn't know where these two other modules are

We need the `--module_resolution` flag and tell CC where the other modules are:

```sh
$ cc --compilation_level ADVANCED \
     --language_out ES5 \
     --process_common_js_modules \
     --module_resolution NODE \
     --js mylib/index.js mylib/inc.js mylib/is_number.js
```

However the output is empty...

Why? In `ADVANCED` compilation mode CC removes any code that is not used. Which is the case actually: so far all this stuff isn't used at all!

Let's check with a less aggressive compilation mode:

```sh
$ cc --compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY --formatting PRETTY_PRINT \
     --language_out ES5 \
     --process_common_js_modules \
     --module_resolution NODE \
     --js mylib/index.js mylib/inc.js mylib/is_number.js
```

```js
var module$mylib$index = {default:{}};
module$mylib$index.default.inc = module$mylib$inc.default;
module$mylib$index.default.utils = {is_number:module$mylib$is_number.default};
var module$mylib$inc = {};
var is_number$$module$mylib$inc = module$mylib$is_number.default;
module$mylib$inc.default = function(x) {
  return (0,module$mylib$is_number.default)(x) ? x + 1 : x;
};
var module$mylib$is_number = {};
module$mylib$is_number.default = function(x) {
  return typeof x === "number";
};
```

We can see that even if the `ADVANCED` compilation mode didn't remove everything, this wouldn't be very useful anyway. Where is `window.mylib` for example?

The only way I managed to get both my library available at `window.mylib` and compiled with the most aggressive compilation mode, is to have a separate exports file for the browser.

From this `mylib/index.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  inc: require('./inc'),
  utils: {
    is_number: require('./is_number')
  }
};
```

To this `mylib/index_browser.js`

```js
window.mylib = {
  inc: require('./inc'),
  utils: {
    is_number: require('./is_number')
  }
};
```

When you add to the `window` object CC knows that this code *may* be reached so it can't safely remove it anymore.

Let's try again with this file:

```sh
$ cc --compilation_level ADVANCED --formatting PRETTY_PRINT \
     --language_out ES5 \
     --process_common_js_modules \
     --module_resolution NODE \
     --js mylib/index_browser.js mylib/inc.js mylib/is_number.js
```

```js
function b(a) {
  return "number" === typeof a;
}
;window.g = {h:function(a) {
  return b(a) ? a + 1 : a;
}, j:{i:b}};
```

That is looking better but there is a major problem: CC has mangled all the names!

Don't worry! We only need to tell which names CC should leave alone. That is the purpose of an externs file.

`mylib/externs.js`

```js
/** @externs */
var foo;
var inc;
var utils;
var is_number;
```

We need another flag: `--externs`

```sh
$ cc --compilation_level ADVANCED --formatting PRETTY_PRINT \
     --language_out ES5 \
     --process_common_js_modules \
     --module_resolution NODE \
     --externs mylib/externs.js \
     --js mylib/index_browser.js mylib/inc.js mylib/is_number.js
```

```js
function b(a) {
  return "number" === typeof a;
}
;window.mylib = {inc:function(a) {
  return b(a) ? a + 1 : a;
}, utils:{is_number:b}};
```

Getting there...

One obvious improvement is to wrap all of this in an IIFE to avoid polluting the global scope more than necessary.

We need the `--isolation_mode` flag:

```sh
$ cc --compilation_level ADVANCED --formatting PRETTY_PRINT \
     --language_out ES5 \
     --process_common_js_modules \
     --module_resolution NODE \
     --externs mylib/externs.js \
     --isolation_mode IIFE \
     --js mylib/index_browser.js mylib/inc.js mylib/is_number.js
```

```js
(function(){function b(a) {
  return "number" === typeof a;
}
;window.mylib = {inc:function(a) {
  return b(a) ? a + 1 : a;
}, utils:{is_number:b}};
}).call(this);
```

Fantastic!

All that is left to do is save that into a file and remove the formatting to save up a few extra bytes:

```sh
$ cc --compilation_level ADVANCED \
     --language_out ES5 \
     --process_common_js_modules \
     --module_resolution NODE \
     --externs mylib/externs.js \
     --isolation_mode IIFE \
     --js mylib/index_browser.js mylib/inc.js mylib/is_number.js \
     --js_output_file mylib/browser.min.js
```

`mylib/browser.min.js`

```js
(function(){function b(a){return"number"===typeof a};window.mylib={inc:function(a){return b(a)?a+1:a},utils:{is_number:b}};}).call(this);
```